# Invalidated single key on properties database

Tags: configuration

For persistent storage our system has used Properties database. The value is incremented per request base. this works fine with single server environment as the application context is same. But creates issue when we have multiple CD servers. Because `PropertyStore` is cached we get different values based on which server the request hits.
e.g. Request comes from cd1. the key is read and stores 1 as value. Now when user submits a form its value gets incremented to 2. for Next hit its value increments to 3 in DB

Now a request comes to CD2. the key is read and stores 3 as value. on submit its value get increments to 4 in DB

Again a request comes to CD1. but because properties data is cached. when user initiate new form submit it values comes 3 and updates to 4 in DB.

```
Sitecore.Context.Database.PropertyStore.GetIntValue(propertyName, 1);
```

So I am trying to invalidate this property cache so for every request it gets new value from Database.

`Sitecore.Context.Database.PropertyStore.Remove` removes the property from database and resets to 1 so that is not an option.

So is there anyway we can invalidate single property or have some configuration to ignore specific property in `PropertyStore` cache?

Comment: Maybe you should just not use the PropertyStore for this...